# how to check exsit or not element selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a specific element on a page.
The page will automatically change the page content after the page is loaded and after certain validations.
So, after the page is loaded, we try to determine whether the page has been loaded or not based on whether there is a specific element in the changed page content.
but it doesn't work

I want to do the following code is executed If the element is found within the specified time.
If I can't find it by that time, Close Selenium Object and the script.

```
    #Waiting for detect Element
    try:
        UserListElement = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mainUserSearchDiv"))
        )
    except TimeoutException: #Can't find element during time.
        print("Cannot find element")
        browser.close #Close selenium.
    finally: #Can find Element
        print("Complite Load Page")
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? What do you mean by `but it doesn't work`? What error appears etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is with `browser.close`.
Instead of `close` it should be `close()`.
So please change from

```py
browser.close
```

to

```py
browser.close()
```

And your code should be correct

Comment: Thank you teaching me! And What's my code wrong, Can you make me know..? I'm a beginner so I don't know what's mean you said not correct at my code.

Comment: You asked this question a year before.... It's very simple. You are missing `()` as I wrote in my answer